# I am 22 years old & 5feet 2inches tall. I wanna become taller. what do I do?

Tags: exercise, bodybuilding, exercise-technique, health, exercise-frequency

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Increase height naturally? Are those ads gimmicks?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6193/how-to-increase-height-naturally-are-those-ads-gimmicks)

I am 22 years old. And I am just 5feet 2inches tall. I wanna become taller. I have heard that there is an injection for this. is it true? What foods should I prefer for this? vegetarian, of-course. What physical exercises should I do? please tell me the best I can do to push my chances of becoming taller at this age? I am planning on tablets like calcium sandoz. what do you think? Please help me.

Comment: You probably won't grow much more taller at that age. Genetics are partly responsible for this. Growth hormone injections exist, but I don't recommend looking at that unless you have specific medical conditions. Please take note that medical questions are off-topic according to the [faq].

Comment: The Growth Hormone stuff you see is not for growth in height, but for other types of growth like muscle. HGH is not something purported to change your height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have poor posture as many gen Y's do from forever tapping on phones, video games and websurfing, correcting it will make the most of what you were given. Keep your joints well hydrated by keeping yourself well hydrated.

Although height is mostly genetic, children can have their growth stunted by lack of sleep, poor diet, drugs or alcohol. At your age you have now stopped growing so anything other than leg implants will do nothing (or close to nothing) to your height.

Edit: just a little story

I did a cooking class many years ago and I was paired with this guy, about 6'2, good looking, good build but you could just see he had no confidence. I was shocked when he said to me, "It sucks to be going bald, doesn't it?"

Answer (score 0):

You can't gain height, but if your reason for gaining height is to play better at sports, you can increase your vertical jump height.

I answered a similar question here: [How to Increase height naturally? Are those ads gimmicks?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6193/how-to-increase-height-naturally-are-those-ads-gimmicks)