# Can I get taller at 17?

Tags: height

I am a 17 year old (turned 17 this feb) teenage boy who is only 5'5" ish tall.. Well to be honest I think it's a little bit over 5'4.5".. But I tell everyone that I'm 5'6".
As you might have guessed, I'm very insecure about my height! Even some girls are taller than me! :( I am still a virgin cause not a single girl likes me as a partner for me being short... They only friendzone me :'(

So do I have any more hope? Can still get taller? I'd even be happy with 5'7"!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about height insecurity, not physical fitness.

Comment: Ah @BKE I didn't realize that as a thing on Physical Fitness SE sorry about that. I'm new here. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Increase height naturally? Are those ads gimmicks?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6193/how-to-increase-height-naturally-are-those-ads-gimmicks)

Comment: @NL628 No, don't delete your answer, even if the question doesn't fit, it doesn't change the validity of your answer

Answer (score 4):

Of course you still have a chance!

As way of example, one of my friends who is in college was 5 foot 4 at age 19, right when he started college. At age 23, right as he was graduating, I went to visit him, and he's 5' 11''!!

Don't worry about your height. I do not want to be offensive or anything, but if you are really focused on girls, and want a long term relationship, you should be with a girl who cares about you as a person, not just your height.

Try not to be to depressed. You as a 17 year old male have not stopped growing. Think about it this way. I have seen older men in their 50's grow 1-3 inches taller *just from doing yoga.* If you increase your height by just 1.5 inches, you'll reach 5'6'' which is a good height! You still have a long way to go, and there's no need to be insecure.

If you truly are extremely depressed, try seeing a doctor or a therapist. Suicide is definitely not the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

It is reasonable to grow up to another couple inches at this stage.  Even into college, while not common, it is also not uncommon to have some growth (needing to hem pants for instance).

Don't get so stressed about it.  Go out for wrestling and boxing as they work for people of all size.  And the confidence of learning combative sports is helpful for shorter men.